# How do you use django forms to save to more than one model?

Tags: django, forms, models

Say I have a single form that has a field type and depending on what type the user inputs, the data is placed into a model/table.  How do you do this with django forms?

Thanks!

Comment: You really need to get familiar with the documentation. This type of question will get quickly voted down or closed. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/

Comment: This question is easily answered by checking the Django documentation. That should be your first point of reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, a form for more than one model is called a [FormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).